# File Download in C# onClick Method through Ajax

Tags: c#, file

SO I have been searching a lot but only found Web Methods of downloading a file from a server or a URL.
My Question is that I have a desktop path of a file (pdf) and I made a table , and on its on click function I call Ajax and on back end I want to download the file from the Desktop. Any body has any idea to give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The file will be on the server in production environment. you can simply use Response.Redirect(Server.Mappath("~/filepath")).

it should prompt an open/save dialog on client browser.

or you can define the content type and use Transmit File.

```
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; 
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.pdf"); 
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/filepath.pdf")); 
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Do i have to add some packages for "Response" and "Server"

Comment: you're building a web app or desktop?

Comment: I am making a web app

Comment: ok i have been now able to open the file in another tab. by putting the path in "href" . but yet i am unable to show the dialogue box to OPEN/SAVE the file?

Comment: href will always open the file in new tab. Use the code I have provided and it should work fine